# Mule SFDC connector: redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=redirect_uri must match configuration

Tags: oauth-2.0, salesforce, mule

I am connecting to SFDC with mule connector by oauth, trying to authorize but getting following error message.

```
<flow name="sfdcFlow1" doc:name="sfdcFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${hostname}" port="${port}" path="sfdc" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <sfdc:authorize config-ref="Salesforce__OAuth_v2_0" display="POPUP" 
    accessTokenUrl="https://na1.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token" 
    authorizationUrl="https://na1.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize"
    doc:name="Salesforce"/>
</flow>
```

getting following error message in the browser:

error:redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=redirect_uri must match configuration

what is redirect or callback url? Do I need to have another flow and http requests?
I made this but didnot work:

```
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${hostname}" port="${port}" path="callback" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger message="===callback====" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Edit:
I have an url from sfdc as: https://cs17.salesforce.com/. IS this is the url to be used for redirect?

Mules ref docs says to use

oauthcallback as path. I am using Anypoint studio with sfdc connector 6.0.1. Even after using same error message I receive it.

```
<sfdc:oauth-callback-config  domain="localhost" localPort="8081"  path="oauthcallback"/>
```

[Mulesoft ref docs](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Salesforce+Connector+Authentication)

[Reference -1](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callback URL is where Salesforce will redirect after successful authentication. I have not used it with Salesforce but I have done this with other cloud connector and you can refer some of my slide share for details. Please try with those links and let me know if u still have any issue.

http://www.slideshare.net/rupeshkrsinha/integration-with-dropbox-using-mule-esb

http://www.slideshare.net/rupeshkrsinha/integrating-with-linkedin-using-mule-esb-linkedin-connector

Comment: Please refer below link for an example.

https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange#!/authenticating-salesforce-using-oauth2